# Find out date difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have `from date` and `to date` in my table, I want to know total number of days between two dates without **sunday**, in SQL Server 2008.

give me a query..

Accept my question...

Comment: There is no such function available - you have `DATEDIFF` - but that's just the difference in days - any day, including Sunday. If you must exclude Sundays, you'll have to do some extra work yourself.

Comment: but,i have more than 1000 records,how to handle this...

Comment: There's a commercial library of SQL-CLR function out there called [SQL# (SQL Sharp)](http://www.sqlsharp.com/) that I believe can handle such requirements (like difference between two dates in "working days")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so work out the total number of days, subtract the total number of weeks, and a fiddle factor for the case where the from date is a Sunday:

```
SELECT
   DATEDIFF(dd, FromDate, ToDate)
  -DATEDIFF(wk, FromDate, ToDate)
  -(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, FromDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: DATEPART(DW, date_value) will work in most cases, but be aware that Sunday is not guaranteed to equal 1 as this value, like DATENAME, also changes per locale. Look in BOL or MSDN for the DATEFIRST session property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766.aspx). Hence, this solution has the same potential problem as the other solutions noted here using DATENAME (though likely the value of DayOfWeek changes less often than the spelling of the day names).

Answer (score 1):

try to use this as an example and work it..

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2008/10/01'
SET @EndDate = '2008/10/31'


SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: I'd be careful about using DATENAME - change your language settings and it no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a CTE, and this couuld easily be turned into a scalar function:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2011-09-01'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2011-09-23'

;WITH DateRange (date) AS
(
    SELECT @startDate 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date+1
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE date<@endDate
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DateRange WHERE DATENAME(dw,Date) != 'Sunday'
```

Returns `20` which is the number of days this month so far which are not sundays.

Here's an equivalent function which can be used:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.NumberOfDaysExcludingSunday(
    @startDate DATETIME,
    @endDate DATETIME
) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rtn INT
;WITH DateRange (date) AS
(
    SELECT @startDate 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date+1
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE date<@endDate
)
SELECT @rtn = COUNT(*) FROM DateRange WHERE DATENAME(dw,Date) != 'Sunday'
RETURN @rtn
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.NumberOfDaysExcludingSunday(startDate,endDate)
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Same as my comment to Stewie, you need to be careful interpreting 'Sunday' because this won't work on systems outside of certain English locales.